# Guardando estado de vários botões em localStorage

Tags: jquery, localstorage

Amigos, tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma lista com um botão em cada linha, eles servem para definir um status. Quando clicados mudam de "aguardando" para "recebido" e é salvo no localStorage.
De modo toggle, eu mudo o texto e adiciono/removo uma classe que estiliza os estados.

Assim:

o HTML:

```
<li><button class="status">aguardando</button></li>
<li><button class="status">aguardando</button></li>
<li><button class="status">aguardando</button></li>
```

o jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var savedText = localStorage.getItem('click');

  if(savedText) {
    $('.status').text(savedText);
  }
});

$('.status').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('texto');
    if($this.hasClass('texto')){
        $this.text('recebido');
        $this.addClass('recebido');
        $this.removeClass('aguardando');
    } else {
        $this.text('aguardando');
        $this.addClass('aguardando');
        $this.removeClass('recebido');
    }
    localStorage.setItem('click', $this.text());
});
```

Então tenho duas dificuldades... uma é que não é salvo no localStorage apenas aquele botão que foi clicado (`$this`), afeta todas as classes e todas ficam com aquele estado após um *refresh*. Isso é até meio óbvio que vá acontecer, só que eu sou leigo demais pra saber como isso poderia ser resolvido, se é que tenha como - sem ter que criar um código pra cada botão separadamente (são dezenaaas).
O segundo é que preciso que o `addClass/removeClass` também seja armazenado com o localStorage, pois até o momento só consegui guardar o texto.

Aqui um fiddle, caso queira: http://jsfiddle.net/hx6qtkvf/2/

Comment: Mas o objetivo é guardar o estado de cada botão separadamente em `localStorage` ? Se sim porque não utiliza um array correspondendo cada botão a uma posição ?

Comment: @Isac, infelizmente não sei como fazer isso. Cê pode me dar um exemplo no jsfiddle?

Comment: Posso mas tenho de perceber melhor como funciona o que você está a tentar fazer. Você alterna com base na classe `texto`, mas nenhum dos seus elementos tem essa classe. E o alternar coloca outras classes, por isso parece meio estranho. As classes coincidem sempre com o texto ou nem por isso ? Por outras palavras, seria necessario guardar as classes no localStorage ou voce consegue reproduzilas pelo texto que o elemento tem ?

Comment: @Isac, eu usei essa classe "texto" só pra conseguir o efeito de alternância (toggle), pra quando clicado mudar e ao clicado novamente voltar ao estado anterior. Te explicando melhor, é assim: tenho dezenas de botões, todos com a palavra "aguardando", com fundo vermelho. Quero que ao clicá-los mudem para "recebido" e com o fundo cor verde. E, muito importante, que isso seja memorizado no localStorage. Ou seja, estando como "recebido" ou "aguardando" continue assim quando a página recarregar.

Comment: Quase cheguei nisso, mas me deparei com o problema de que todos os botões eram afetados. Tipo, cliquei em 1 deles e, ao recarregar, todos estavam com o mesmo texto, sendo que só ele devia ser memorizado. Então não sei como fazer para que memorize cada um por si sem ter que repetir o código dezenas de vezes, com cada botão com um id ou classe diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu sugeri em comentário, o melhor é guardar o estado de tudo em `localStorage`, como um array de elementos. Para o que pretende fazer basta guardar um array com a classe a aplicar a cada botão, sendo que a aplicação é feita pela ordem com que os botões aparecem na página. Ou seja a classe na posição 0 aplica no primeiro botão, a da posição 1 no segundo botão e assim sucessivamente.

Como tem de guardar sempre uma string, pode guardar o array todo como JSON através do método `JSON.parse`. Depois para recuperar o que ficou guardado basta aplicar o processo inverso com `JSON.stringify`.

Para simplificar transformei o seu código de alteração de estado numa função aplicável a qualquer botão.

Solução:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function alternaEstado(botao){
        if(botao.hasClass('aguardando')){
            botao.text('recebido');
            botao.addClass('recebido');
            botao.removeClass('aguardando');
        } else {
            botao.text('aguardando');
            botao.addClass('aguardando');
            botao.removeClass('recebido');
        }
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //obter o array de classes pelo localStorage
        let classesBotoes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("botoes"));
        if (classesBotoes === null){ //se nao houver constroi o array com base nas classes do html
            classesBotoes = [];
            $(".status").each(function(posicao){
                classesBotoes[posicao] = $(this).hasClass('aguardando') ? 'aguardando' : 'recebido';
            });
        }

        //aplica o array de classes nos botões que estão na página
        $(".status").each(function(posicao){
            let classe = classesBotoes[posicao];
            $(this).removeClass('recebido aguardando').addClass(classe).text(classe);
        });

        //no click de cada botão, altera a classe no array e guarda o array todo de novo em localStorage
        $('.status').click(function(){
            alternaEstado($(this));
            let posicaoClicada = $(".status").index($(this)); 
            classesBotoes[posicaoClicada] = $(this).hasClass('aguardando') ? 'aguardando' : 'recebido';     
            localStorage.setItem("botoes", JSON.stringify(classesBotoes));
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .aguardando {
        background-color:red;
    }
    .recebido {
        background-color:green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <li><button class="status aguardando">aguardando</button></li>
    <li><button class="status aguardando">aguardando</button></li>
    <li><button class="status aguardando">aguardando</button></li>
</body>
</html>
```

Por simplicidade deixei que o texto a ser atribuído aos botões fosse o correspondente à classe que eles tem:

```
let classe = classesBotoes[posicao];
$(this).removeClass('recebido aguardando').addClass(classe).text(classe);
//                                                     ^------------^
```

Você pode aplicar outro texto qualquer, mas nesse caso tem aplicar uma lógica adicional para gerar o texto com base na classe que o elemento tem.

Comment: Muito bem explicado e funciona perfeitamente. MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra Sem problema, estamos ca para ajudar :)